# CSS transitions with Angular 2+ ngClass

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions, getter

I have a dead simple CSS class that toggles opacity on `<tr>` elements with a basic ease transition:

```
 tbody tr {
   transition: opacity 1s ease;
 }

 tbody.blur tr {
   opacity: .3;
 }

 tbody.blur tr.focus {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

`[ngClass]` sets and removes the `.blur` and `.focus` classes. (The point is to blur all rows except one focused row.) The opacity works as expected, but the transition doesn't. If I type the classes directly into the `tbody` and `tr` tags with dev tools, the opacity transitions, but if the classes are set by `ngClass`, there's no transition.

I tried setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, but that had no impact.

Am I missing something with transitions and `ngClass`?

Edit: ngClass code is basically

```
<tbody [ngClass]="{blur: focused > -1}">
  <tr [ngClass]="{focus: focused === item.id}" *ngFor="let item of items">
```

The component class has a focused variable that is set to -1 on blur and to the respective id on focus.

**Edit - solution**

A computed getter that continually returns a new Array instance prevents the CSS transition; example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmlat?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). If you return the same array instance, the [transition occurs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5bf2w?file=app/form.component.ts). The getter should return the same, mutable property of the class instance like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihljgg?file=app%2Fform.component.ts). Note that the property in the latter example is made up of other getters, which is fine.

Comment: Please add the code. Where did you add the CSS?

Comment: Paste ngClass code please!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, CSS is added to the component.css file created by the CLI.

Comment: You should prefer `[class.blur]="focused > -1"` if the class name is fixed (and `[class.focus]="focused === item.id"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nice tip; thanks.

Comment: Does the transition work if you take `blur` out of the equation (with selectors `tbody tr` and `tbody tr.focus`)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan good inquiry yet no; that still gave me opacity logic but no transition.

Comment: I think the problem is your `focused` logic. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-932zin If you click into the right `<input>` then `focused` is set to `-1` to get `.blur` removed. If you click back into an input inside the table, then the transition works. It probably does not exactly work yet as you want, but that is only caused by the logic when you add or remove the CSS classes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks a ton - I'll reproduce the components on the fiddle you created.

Comment: Now it might be closer to what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-932zin

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks so much for your help - actually this involves an event emitter and a passed down state coming from multiple computed getters - maybe the timing of the update is impacting the transition. I couldn't distill and reproduce the logic yet, and it's 2am here. Thanks a lot, really. I'll post something tomorrow if you're still available.

Comment: Leave a comment and I'll have a look when I have time

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Explanation is in edit above; example is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxklrk?file=app%2Fform.component.ts

Comment: The StackBlitz contains way too much code. Please reduce it to the absolute minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer apologies. Further reduced: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmlat?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts

Comment: It looks better, but now I'm missing the CSS that is supposed to cause transitions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It's the getter. If tableData is set to a fixed array, the transition works. If it's returned from a getter, the transition doesn't work. Hmm... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5bf2w?file=app/form.component.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer table.component has this style for the transition    transition: opacity 1s ease;

Comment: Sorry, found the styles. They are still inline in the `app-table` component

Comment: Anyway, I guess the question changes to, 'How to use transitions with a typescript / Angular getter'. Strange, huh? Thanks a bunch for working together on that!

Comment: If you have a getter or function that returns a new array instance every time it is called, then Angular will endlessly update, this prevents any animation. In general, you can consider such a patter a bug in Angular. It should be like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuptwx, then the same array instance is returned every time and Angular can cope with that just fine.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ah - ok. Hmm... I did a large app in Vue and I relied heavily on its computed properties functionality. I can't find a similar thing in Angular. I guess we have to track events more closely and manually call functions. That certainly changes the way I write js - even in older apps I used native get() properties a lot. Maybe an observable can solve this somehow. Anyway man - thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use getters, but you must not return a different instance of the object or array if it hasn't changed. Angular relies on object identity for change detection. If you return a new instance every time as you did in your StackBlitz Angular assumes an ever-changing value. This completely breaks Angulars change detection.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hey wow - that's it. If the getter just points to some class property, it works, even if that class property is computed from other getters. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihljgg?file=app%2Fform.component.ts
Thanks - if you'd like a quick accepted answer of course I'd accept it. I can do the write up above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter like

```
  get tableData() {
    return [
        {id: 1, name: 'One', data: this.one},
        {id: 2, name: 'Two', data: this.two},
        {id: 3, name: 'Three', data: this.three},
        {id: 4, name: 'Four', data: this.four},
        {id: 5, name: 'Five', data: this.five},
        {id: 6, name: 'Six', data: this.six}
    ];
  }
```

returns a new array instance every time `tableData` is called. Angular calls the getter every time change detection runs and detects a change because it gets a different instance. This causes severe performance issues and breaks animation, because animation doesn't work if the items are constantly recreated.

A better approach is

```
class MyComponent {  
  data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'One', data: this.one},
    {id: 2, name: 'Two', data: this.two},
    {id: 3, name: 'Three', data: this.three},
    {id: 4, name: 'Four', data: this.four},
    {id: 5, name: 'Five', data: this.five},
    {id: 6, name: 'Six', data: this.six}
  ];

  get tableData() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

this way Angular change detection gets the same instance every time it calls `tableData` and Angular will be happy.
If some event causes the content or the whole array to change, this is fine of course, but it shouldn't change just because Angular checks twice subsequently.